# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation - App Only

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Im having trouble with endpoint when using the **client_credentials** Grant type (http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

I get

```
{#333 ▼
  +"error": {#314 ▼
    +"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied"
    +"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    +"innerError": {#304 ▼
      +"request-id": "37643af9-b9e9-4771-924f-b34c0e9d0d87"
      +"date": "2016-06-22T13:38:06"
    }
  }
}
```

Im able to get my oauth token no problem using the client credentials grant

```
{#319 ▼
  +"token_type": "Bearer"
  +"expires_in": "3600"
  +"ext_expires_in": "3600"
  +"expires_on": "1466606585"
  +"not_before": "1466602685"
  +"resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com"
  +"access_token": "OMITTED"
}
```

I have also selected the proper application permission

```
Read all users' full profiles
```

[image: Read all users' full profiles]

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you made an update to the permissions, has the admin consented the app after the update was made? Also, if you copy your access token here: http://jwt.calebb.net/ what value do you get in the roles claim?

Comment: Sounds wrong to give you an access token, also I created it via as an admin.

Comment: jwt.calebb.net will decode the access token for you. This just confirms what data (in particular the scopes) are coming through in the token.

All registrations are created by an admin, this is not the same as authorizing it however. You still need to go through the Auth workflow as an admin in order to consent to the access requested.

Comment: @lukepolo: Yina and Marc are not asking for you to paste your token here. We're asking you to decode your token using a tool, so that you can tell us if a role claim is present and what values it has.

Comment: I found that it takes the system between 10-30 mins to correct the permissions. It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions take time (10-30 mins) to propagate